# Disable cilck event when value is zero then display a notification popup when hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml, tailwind-css

please help me on my problem. Bear with me, I am newbie to Ruby on Rails using HAML.

**I have a tab where displays the count of cards.**
See below..

[image]

Some tabs doesn't have a count since I haven't added anything under that table.
I'd like to disable and not display the count if value is ZERO and show a note when hovered.
Been stucked on this for a long time. Can you help me or give me a hint on how I should go about this? Should I make a helper? or Add Conditional statement before the tab code black starts?
If you have your own solution feel free to answer that would be very appreciated.

Here are my codes for the above photo.

```
    -tab_classes = "px-2 cursor-pointer border-transparent text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-700 hover:border-gray-300 whitespace-nowrap py-4 px-1 border-b-2 font-bold text-base"
    
  
    %a{class: tab_classes, data: {main_feed_target: "blockTypeTab", id: "all", action: "click->main-feed#blockTypeChange"}}
      = E('all_cards_bar')
      = "(#{@blocks.length})"
    %a{class: tab_classes, data: {main_feed_target: "blockTypeTab", id: "pods", action: "click->main-feed#blockTypeChange"}}
      = E('pods_cards_bar')
      = "(#{@blocks.pods.length})"          
    %a{class: tab_classes, data: {main_feed_target: "blockTypeTab", id: "tweets", action: "click->main-feed#blockTypeChange"}}
      = E('tweets_cards_bar')
      = "(#{@blocks.tweets.length})"
    %a{class: tab_classes, data: {main_feed_target: "blockTypeTab", id: "vids", action: "click->main-feed#blockTypeChange"}}
      = E('vids_cards_bar')
      = "(#{@blocks.vids.length})"
    %a{class: tab_classes, data: {main_feed_target: "blockTypeTab", id: "blogs", action: "click->main-feed#blockTypeChange"}}
      = E('blogs_cards_bar')
      = "(#{@blocks.blogs.length})"
```

I am using HAML and Tailwind classes for CSS.

Thank you!!

Comment: [No images of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) please

Comment: Thank you! Changed it to plain code text now.